# iOS - how to make the record audio file small (just like WeChat does)?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiorecorder

I used the following setting to make the recorded audio file smaller

```
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];                                                                              
[settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
//Encoder
[settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:12000] forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
[settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey];    [settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey];
[settings setValue :AVAudioQualityMin forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
```

But, for 60 second of sound, it takes me around 100K while wechat only takes around 30K. Does anyone know how do they manage to do this? Or does anyone have ideas how I can further squeeze the size? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
[settings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
```

**kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC** is having smallest size.

And then you can break file into multiple small chunks. For reference see the link below:

http://sspbond007.blogspot.in/2012/01/objective-c-filesplitter-and-joiner.html

Comment: I have seen on the Internet that someone changed the .caf to .amr file, and made it to 30K per minute by using something called "speex". Have you heard about it? However, this stuff seems too advanced for a beginner like me. So, I would like to know if there is any simpler way to do it?